# EVPN+VxLAN strange silent host issue

Tags: cisco, network, bgp, arp, evpn

EVPN+VxLAN very strange silent host issue
I have very basic EVPN+VxLAN design where i used OSPF/Multicast/BGP/vPC technologies to build small size datacenter. L2VNI working great without any issue. I have ISP connectivity via Border-Leaf and issue is when i spin up VM using public IP then its not pinging from outside world until unless i logged into vm and ping 8.8.8.8 (I believe it generate BGP l3vni route on border-leaf and then it learn about that vm and everything start pinging from inside and outside)

[image]

Question: why it's only issue with Public IPs which using border-leaf. I haven't seen same issue with my internal L2VNI network. I think when someone from outside trying to ping my public IP vm then border-leaf should generate ARP broadcast to find mac address of VM (am i missing something here?)

In my following config you can see i didn't create anycast-gateway on border-leaf also didn't create VNI 10100, is that correct or i should create anycast-gateway and L2VNI on border-leaf?

My border-leaf config:

```
nv overlay evpn
feature ospf
feature bgp
feature pim
feature interface-vlan
feature vn-segment-vlan-based
feature lacp
feature bfd
feature nv overlay

ip pim rp-address 10.255.0.123 group-list 239.0.0.0/8
ip pim ssm range 232.0.0.0/8
vlan 1,555
vlan 555
  name L3VNI-For-IRB
  vn-segment 10555

vrf context RED
  description ** VRF-RED **
  vni 10555
  rd auto
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    route-target both auto
    route-target both auto evpn

interface Vlan555
  description ** L3VNI-For-IRB **
  no shutdown
  vrf member RED
  ip forward
  ipv6 address use-link-local-only

interface nve1
  no shutdown
  host-reachability protocol bgp
  source-interface loopback1
  member vni 10555 associate-vrf

interface loopback1
  description ** VTEP/Overlay **
  ip address 10.255.255.1/32
  ip ospf authentication-key 3 fa3ab8e90610229c
  ip router ospf UNDERLAY-NET area 0.0.0.0
  ip pim sparse-mode

router ospf UNDERLAY-NET
  log-adjacency-changes
  area 0.0.0.0 authentication
router bgp 65001
  router-id 10.255.1.1
  log-neighbor-changes
  template peer VXLAN_SPINE
    remote-as 65001
    update-source loopback0
    address-family ipv4 unicast
    address-family l2vpn evpn
      send-community
      send-community extended
  neighbor 10.255.0.1
    inherit peer VXLAN_SPINE
    description ** iBGP Peer to Spine-1 **
    no shutdown
  neighbor 10.255.0.2
    inherit peer VXLAN_SPINE
    description ** iBGP Peer to Spine-2 **
    no shutdown
  vrf RED
    log-neighbor-changes
    address-family ipv4 unicast
      aggregate-address 60.25.124.0/23 summary-only
    address-family ipv6 unicast
    neighbor 2001:c05:3002:3::1
      bfd
      remote-as 21855
      local-as 293218
      description ** IPv6 ISP eBGP peer to Border5 **
      address-family ipv6 unicast
        send-community
    neighbor 60.25.120.201
      bfd
      remote-as 21855
      local-as 293218
      description ** ISP eBGP peer to Border5 **
      address-family ipv4 unicast
        send-community
        route-map LOCAL_PREF_150_IN in
```

My Leaf-1 config (I have vPC pair so i am just posting leaf-1 config)

```
nv overlay evpn
feature ospf
feature bgp
feature pim
feature fabric forwarding
feature interface-vlan
feature vn-segment-vlan-based
feature lacp
feature vpc
feature nv overlay

fabric forwarding anycast-gateway-mac 0000.dead.beef
ip pim rp-address 10.255.0.123 group-list 239.0.0.0/8
ip pim ssm range 232.0.0.0/8
vlan 1,60-62,64,100,444,555

vlan 60
  name ostack_1_br-storage
  vn-segment 10060
vlan 61
  name ostack_1_ceph_replication
  vn-segment 10061
vlan 62
  name ostack_1_br-lbaas
  vn-segment 10062
vlan 64
  name inside
  vn-segment 10064
vlan 100
  name ostack_1_public_1
  vn-segment 10100
vlan 444
  name BACKUP_VLAN_ROUTING_VPC
vlan 555
  name L3VNI-For-IRB
  vn-segment 10555

vrf context RED
  vni 10555
  rd auto
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    route-target both auto
    route-target both auto evpn

vpc domain 1
  peer-switch
  role priority 10
  peer-keepalive destination 172.30.0.32 source 172.30.0.31
  delay restore 90
  peer-gateway
  delay restore interface-vlan 30
  ipv6 nd synchronize
  ip arp synchronize

interface Vlan100
  description ** Anycast Gateway For Public  **
  no shutdown
  mtu 9216
  vrf member RED
  ip address 60.25.124.1/23
  ipv6 address 2001:c05:3011::1/64
  ipv6 nd prefix default no-advertise
  ipv6 nd ra route suppress
  no ipv6 redirects
  fabric forwarding mode anycast-gateway

interface Vlan444
  description ** Underlay Backup over vPC Peer-Link **
  no shutdown
  ip address 192.168.1.1/30
  ip ospf authentication-key 3 fa3ab8e90610229c
  ip ospf network point-to-point
  ip router ospf UNDERLAY-NET area 0.0.0.0
  ip pim sparse-mode

interface Vlan555
  description ** L3VNI-For-IRB **
  no shutdown
  mtu 9216
  vrf member RED
  ip forward
  ipv6 address use-link-local-only


interface nve1
  no shutdown
  description ** VTEP/NVE Interface **
  host-reachability protocol bgp
  source-interface loopback1
  member vni 10060
    mcast-group 239.1.1.1
  member vni 10061
    mcast-group 239.1.1.1
  member vni 10062
    mcast-group 239.1.1.1
  member vni 10064
    mcast-group 239.1.1.1
  member vni 10100
    mcast-group 239.1.1.1
member vni 10555 associate-vrf

router ospf UNDERLAY-NET
  router-id 10.255.1.11
  log-adjacency-changes
  area 0.0.0.0 authentication
router bgp 65001
  router-id 10.255.1.11
  log-neighbor-changes
  template peer VXLAN_SPINE
    remote-as 65001
    update-source loopback0
    address-family ipv4 unicast
    address-family l2vpn evpn
      send-community
      send-community extended
  neighbor 10.255.0.1
    inherit peer VXLAN_SPINE
    description ** iBGP Peer to Spine-1 **
  neighbor 10.255.0.2
    inherit peer VXLAN_SPINE
    description ** iBGP Peer to Spine-2 **
  vrf RED
    log-neighbor-changes
    address-family ipv4 unicast
      redistribute direct route-map DIRECT-PERMIT-ALL
    address-family ipv6 unicast
      redistribute direct route-map DIRECT-PERMIT-ALL

evpn
  vni 10060 l2
    rd auto
    route-target import auto
    route-target export auto
  vni 10061 l2
    rd auto
    route-target import auto
    route-target export auto
  vni 10062 l2
    rd auto
    route-target import auto
    route-target export auto
  vni 10064 l2
    rd auto
    route-target import auto
    route-target export auto
vni 10100 l2
    rd auto
    route-target import auto
    route-target export auto
```

**Question:** If border-leaf doesn't have any VTEP then how does it discover silent host located on other leaf using BUM traffic?